# Проблема с отображениям постов в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Я хочу вывести посты в wordpress с помощью вот такого кода:

```
<?php if(have_posts(){
   while(have_posts()){
   the_post(); ?>
<h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php }}?>
```

Но у меня выводиться названия страницы а не пост
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите информацию о get_posts или WP_Query. Пример вывода записей:

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'category'    => 0,
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'include'     => array(),
    'exclude'     => array(),
    'post_type'   => 'post',
) );

foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    the_title();
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс цикла WP
```

Хотя возможно вам нужно перейти Внешний вид => Настроить => Настройки главной страницы.
На главной отображать "Статическую страницу" и выбрать страницу с выводом записи.

Comment: Второй способ точно не работает, я так сделал, на счет первого я попробую и отпишусь, у меня есть подозрения что это происходит из-за меню, когда я ставлю в меню не произвольные ссылки а страницы, то происходит такая фигня, судя по том что когда я так не делал все работало, но тогда вопрос как быть )?

Comment: Спасибо, заработало